# How to create a page layout with 4 sections?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to split the page in 4 parts, but with different sizes. With the following code, i get 2 parts horizontally.

But when i want to insert the first vertical in the green area, only a part is displayed...

I need look like this: http://prntscr.com/mp1sxi

This is my code:

```css
#top,
#bottom,
#right,
#left.
 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50%;
}

#top {
    top: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20%;
}

#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
    height: 80%
}

#right {
    right: 0;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 20%;
}

#left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">top

</div>

<div id="bottom">bottom
    <div id="left">top</div>
</div>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: You should learn flexboxes or grids in CSS3. They give you awesome possibilities like this in an easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;

}

#top,
#bottom,
#right,
#left {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

#top {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: palevioletred;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}

#bottom {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
    height: 20%;
    width: 80%;
}

#right {
    right: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20%;
    top: 20%;
    height: 80%;
}

#left {
    left: 0;
    width: 80%;
    top: 20%;
    height: 60%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top">top</div>
  <div id="left">Left</div>
  <div id="right">Right</div>
  <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</body>
</html>
```